# There May Be Problem In My Route In my Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

There is an undefined variable error on my page.
I am working with a package chatter and I am adding a field to add comments to the post like StackOverflow.
But when I am routing the ChatterReplyController@show and passing $chatterreplies variable the view page is showing undefined variable.

This is the code of controller

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $chatterreplies = Chatterreply::where('chatter_post_id',$id)->get();
        echo "<pre>"; print_r('$chatterreplies'); die();

  // or use the laravel helper 
  dd($chatterreplies);
        return view('chatter::discussion', compact('chatterreplies'));

    }
```

Route File Code Post Group

```
Route::group([
    'as'     => 'posts.',
    'prefix' => $route('post', 'posts'),
], function () use ($middleware, $authMiddleware) {

    // All posts view.
    Route::get('/', [
        'as'         => 'index',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@index',
        'middleware' => $middleware('post.index'),
    ]);

    // Create post view.
    Route::get('create', [
        'as'         => 'create',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@create',
        'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.create'),
    ]);

    // Store post action.
    Route::post('/', [
        'as'         => 'store',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterPostController@store',
        'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.store'),
    ]);
    //Adding Comments
    Route::post('/reply/{id}', [
        'as'         => 'store',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterReplyController@store',
        'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.reply.store'),
    ]);
    //showing Comment
    Route::get('/reply/{id}', [
        'as'         => 'show',
        'uses'       => 'ChatterReplyController@show',
        'middleware' => $authMiddleware('post.reply.show'),
    ]);
```

And Here is how I am showing my content on the view page

```
@foreach($chatterreplies as $chatterreply)
                        {{$chatterreply->reply}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: try change compact for `->with('chatterreplies',$chatterreplies );`

Comment: no same error is there again @AlexanderVillalobos  please check my route may be there is a problem and should I share the error screen

Comment: you pass two parameters and you route have one

Comment: delete this in your function `Chatterreply $chatterreply`

Comment: I deleted that @AlexanderVillalobos , but error is still there

Comment: try with  **return view('chatter.discussion', compact('chatterreplies'));**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function show($id)
 {
    $chatterreplies = Chatterreply::where('chatter_post_id',$id)->get();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r('$chatterreplies'); die();
    return view('chatter::discussion', compact('chatterreplies'));

 }
```

in your `route` you pass one `parameter`

Comment: you verified if you pass id ?? try print `dd($id);`

Comment: if you have time sir may you please see it through Teamviewer because of no change.

Comment: like this ` return view('chatter::discussion', compact('chatterreplies'));`

Comment: `@foreach($chatterreplies as $chatterreply)
          {{$chatterreply->reply}}
          @endforeach`  I first called it in route

Comment: 1077484234    pass: 1410

Comment: sorry I lost your Email ID   here is the link to download code zip file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nGCrSRw3B-cuUQ96Gy5td_tO2Nx2A7za/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the controllers are present in vendors<devdojo<chatter<src<controller .

Comment: my email is bhanotvardana@gmail.com

Comment: Sir would you please help me today